# how to display custom header text in radgrid

Tags: asp.net

i write this code for change header text in radgrid but encounter with this problem:
please help me

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

my code is : `RadGrid1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Rank";`

Comment: are you using AutoGenerated columns? when are you executing your code?

Answer (score 1):

For Auto generated Columns.

```
protected void RadGrid1_ColumnCreated(object sender, GridColumnCreatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.UniqueName == "FirstName") // Uniuename is your DataFieldName
    {
        e.Column.HeaderText = "Name";
    }
}
```

For Static Columns.

ASPX

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="FirstName" DataField="FirstName"
        UniqueName="FirstName">
      </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```

C#

```
if (RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Columns.FindByUniqueName("FirstName") != null)
    {
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Columns.FindByUniqueName("FirstName").HeaderText = "Name";
    }
```